# How to exclude a specific test with Gradle 8.1.1 on cli?

Tags: gradle, junit

I am trying to exclude a specific test that does not work on Windows but on the Linux machines.

I run: `./gradlew test --no-daemon -PexcludeTests="**/LinuxTest"`

I also tried: `./gradlew test --no-daemon -PexcludeTests="my.company.project.LinuxTest"`

But both execute the test.

Is there a way to control this via command line?